# Select href from HTML table using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have HTML table:

```
<table class="table_class" id="table_id"
<tbody>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>
        <a href=""/link/123">...</a>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

And need to get all such hrefs from 1 column in table.
I tried to use

```
Elements links = table.select("a[href]");
System.out.println(links);
```

but it parse hrefs from a tags on complete page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
String url = "...";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elements = doc.select("#table_id a[href]");
```